# In Sveltkit, how do i import SCSS variables into my JS?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, svelte, sveltekit

Im trying to access my color pallete within the script tag of my component:

```js
import pallete from "$src/style/pallete.scss";
```

but it is returning the export as a string:

```
:export {
  mainColor: #e8d44d;
  mainColorHover: #c0aa1d;
  mainColorContrast: #1e1e1e;
  mainContrastDark: #000000;
}
```

I know i need to add these webpack configurations as said in some articles that i read in my searching, like [this one](https://css-tricks.com/getting-javascript-to-talk-to-css-and-sass/#aa-sass-variables-and-javascript).

```
module.exports = {
 // ...
 module: {
  rules: [
   {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
   },
   // ...
  ]
 }
};
```

but im fallowing the [Sveltekit docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/migrating#project-files-configuration) so i have no `webpack.config.js` or `rollup.config.js`

> Your `webpack.config.js` or `rollup.config.js` should be replaced with a `svelte.config.js`, as documented [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration).

What should i do?

Comment: SvelteKit uses Vite. If you want to do something other than importing the styles you probably need a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [unlocomqx](https://www.reddit.com/u/unlocomqx/) said on Reddit, im now using [vite-plugin-css-export](https://npm.io/package/vite-plugin-css-export)

Answer (score 1):

It's not response to your question, but I would recommend you different approach

With pure css variables you can do almost everythng as with scss vars

```
html {
  --mainColor: #e8d44d;
  --mainColorHover: #c0aa1d;
  --mainColorContrast: #1e1e1e;
  --mainContrastDark: #000000;
}
```

And then read it with JS

```
getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue('--mainColor')
```

Only case you may need variables on SCSS level is when you use them as argument of SCSS functions. In such case you can still declare CSS variables based base on SCSS vars and get best of both approaches.

Comment: I want do access my variables in JS, not in SCSS, to do things with it, in the post i mentioned: https://css-tricks.com/getting-javascript-to-talk-to-css-and-sass/#aa-sass-variables-and-javascript this is possible using webpack or rollup configuration

Comment: Someone said that on Reddit too, it is indeed a clever way to make that.
https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/16ovkmq/comment/k1q5tx3/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3